Selecting rows based on multiple criteria
The fields I have are:
ID, QUOTE_ID, REASON, DECISION, PARTNER, REQUEST_LIMIT, APPROVED_LIMIT

In a nutshell someone is getting this report each month in Excel and transforming the data based on criteria of the columns.
There can be multiple QUOTE_IDs per ID e.g. ID 1 and then QUOTE_ID 1,2,3 on three rows. Each can have a different request limit, approved limit, decision etc.
For brevity without listing the full criteria is it possible to build this into a select query?
E.g.



ID
QUOTE_ID
REASON
DECISION
PARTNER
REQUEST_LIMIT
APPROVED_LIMIT




1
101
New Application
Decline
J&co
100
0


2
101
Additional info
Decline
J&co
100
0


3
101
Additional info
Decline
J&co
100
100


4
101
Appeal Decision
Approved
NewPartner
200
200



In this table the final rows that would end up in the query would be 3 and 4 as this is a final approval with new partner and a limit change. The first row is ignored because the second request has been raised requesting additional info.
Honestly not sure it's at all possible but thought I'd ask! Any help is much appreciated.
I have tried row_number() over partition etc. which might be the correct path to go down but unsure

oh I am sorry - the initial table was still in markdown mode and was a mess! Updated now

As said, you please should provide both input data and expected outcome in your question, currently you missed at least one of them. And explain the intended logic much more detailed. If I understand correct, you only need row 3 and 4 and would like to filter out row 1 and 2? So why not simply check that request_limit = approved_limit? I guess this is not sufficient, so you need to improve your description.

"The first row is ignored because the second request..." -- How can you tell which row is the first one, second one, etc.? Remember that in relational databases rows do not have inherent ordering.

Your explanation of the fields ID and QUOTE_ID seems to be reversed in the example (or it's a many-to-many relationship?). More important: you need to tell us about the criteria (at least, a simple version of it). Why are you keeping rows 3 & 4? If the selection of one row depends on the content of another (related) one, analytical functions MAY BE the way to go.

As The Impaler pointed out, there is no unique ordering. You would either need a REQUEST_ID (auto incremental number) or a timestamp. So you can look DESC and find what you are after.

YOu can use LAG function to acheive the same
        select ID,
           QUOTE_ID,
           REASON,
           DECISION,
           PARTNER,
           REQUEST_LIMIT,
           APPROVED_LIMIT
      from (select ID,
                   QUOTE_ID,
                   REASON,
                   DECISION,
                   PARTNER,
                   REQUEST_LIMIT,
                   lag(APPROVED_LIMIT, 1, 0) over(order by ID) 
                   PREV_APPROVED_LIMIT,
                   APPROVED_LIMIT
              from your_TABLE a)
     where PREV_APPROVED_LIMIT <> APPROVED_LIMIT


This is quite unclear regarding the data structure and logic. Could it be something like here ?
Used Case expressions and analytic functions to describe the logic and flag the rows to be selected. You can adjust it to meet your actual context. Be aware that Case expressions are sequential and the order of conditions is crucial for adequate functionality...
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( ID, QUOTE_ID, REASON, DECISION, PARTNER, REQUEST_LIMIT, APPROVED_LIMIT ) AS
        ( Select 1, 101, 'New Application', 'Decline', 'J' || '&' || 'co', 100, 0 From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, 101, 'Additional info', 'Decline', 'J' || '&' || 'co', 100, 0 From Dual Union All 
          Select 3, 101, 'Additional info', 'Decline', 'J' || '&' || 'co', 100, 100 From Dual Union All 
          Select 4, 101, 'Appeal Decision', 'Approved', 'NewPartner', 200,  200 From Dual 
        ) 

--      S Q L :
 Select   ID, QUOTE_ID, REASON, DECISION, PARTNER, REQUEST_LIMIT, APPROVED_LIMIT,
          Case  When Lead(DECISION, 1, 'Decline') Over(Partition By QUOTE_ID Order By ID) = 'Approved' 
                Then 
                      Case  When REQUEST_LIMIT = Lead(REQUEST_LIMIT, 1) Over(Partition By QUOTE_ID Order By ID) 
                            Then 'Last reason before approval - Limit not changed'
                      Else  'Last reason before approval - Approved limit changed to ' ||
                              Lead(REQUEST_LIMIT, 1) Over(Partition By QUOTE_ID Order By ID)
                      End
                When DECISION = 'Approved'
                Then 'Approval row'
                
                When Lead(DECISION, 1, 'Decline') Over(Partition By QUOTE_ID Order By ID) = 'Decline' 
                Then 'Next decision is Decline'
          Else '? ? ?'
          End "DESCRIPTION",
          --
          Case  When Lead(DECISION, 1, 'Decline') Over(Partition By QUOTE_ID Order By ID) = 'Approved' 
                Then 'Y'
                When DECISION = 'Approved'
                Then 'Y'
                When Lead(DECISION, 1, 'Decline') Over(Partition By QUOTE_ID Order By ID) = 'Decline' 
                Then 'N'
          Else '?'
          End "SHOULD_BE_SELECTED"
From      tbl

/*      R e s u l t :
        ID   QUOTE_ID REASON          DECISION PARTNER    REQUEST_LIMIT APPROVED_LIMIT DESCRIPTION                                                  SHOULD_BE_SELECTED
---------- ---------- --------------- -------- ---------- ------------- -------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------
         1        101 New Application Decline  J&co                 100              0 Next decision is Decline                                     N
         2        101 Additional info Decline  J&co                 100              0 Next decision is Decline                                     N
         3        101 Additional info Decline  J&co                 100            100 Last reason before approval - Approved limit changed to 200  Y
         4        101 Appeal Decision Approved NewPartner           200            200 Approval row                                                 Y                   */

If so - just select rows Where SHOULD_BE_SELECTED = 'Y'
